# SystemRescue identifeis my NVMe drive, but Ubuntu installation doesn't

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, live-usb, grubrescue, nvme

I've seen many posts on problem installing Ubuntu on NVMe drives, none helped so far. In my case:

- SystemRescue live cd does recognize the drive, but Ubuntu installation doesn't, so I am sure that BIOS is correct.
- I had Ubuntu Server 22.04 installed there, but after installing a Nvidia driver signed, I was not able anymore.
- I had since reset BIOS, and confirmed the driver is working correctly via SystemRescue, but Ubuntu will not see the drives anymore.

I have tried enabling some NVMe driver via command line during boot without success, assuming I did it right. Message on Ubuntu 22.04 server is "Block probing did not discover any disks. Unfortunately this means that installation will not be possible." Any advice would be appreciated.

My hardware:

- MSI GT73VR 6RF Titan Pro
- Samsung 970 EVO Plus

Comment: Do you have latest firmware for both UEFI & SSD? `udisksctl status` They used to have one ISO for each model. I see now one listed for many models. https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/ My older desktop uses AHCI driver, but newer one uses VMD (RAID) driver even though not RAID. Both have Samsung NVMe drives.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. In the end, I switched the M2 slot and it worked. I think the M2 slot that I was using had an issue and SystemRescue has more relisient parameters to deal with drives. Just a theory.